# Ability to access specific values from helper in Meteor

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

In my meteor application I want to selectively access values within my page.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  var percentageData = [
    {
      percent_type : 'online',
      percentage: '20'
    },
    {
      percent_type : 'offline',
      percentage: '55'
    }
  ];

  Template.authenticated_user.helpers({
    percentInformation: percentageData
  })
}
```

Here, I return a simple JSON to my template.

```
<template name="authenticated_user">

</template>
```

What I want, is to be able to place on the page parts of this JSON in different places.

For example:

`<div id = {{percentInformation[0].percent_type}}></div>` to assign the id to 'online'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, the only caveat is that you use dot notation for array members as well:

```
{{percentInformation.[0].percent_type}}
```